# NSDate makes application crash between ViewWillAppear() and ViewDidAppear()

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

I am developping an application for iOS in Swift language that crashes with a very vague error message.

First, a little context: I have a custom class `Order`, subclass of `NSManagedObject`, and I am using CoreData for data storage. `Order` has a lot of fields, but two of them are `deliveryDate` and `cCommissionDate`.

I have a TabController with four Tabs, that I use to show all the order information. In the first Tab, there are many `TextField`s, two of them are `deliveryDateText` and `cCommissionDateText`. These two are absolutely identical.

Ok, I populate these fields on the tab's `ViewWillAppear` method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
if let controller = self.parentViewController as? OrderDetailTabBarController {

            let order = getOrder()!

            [...]

            fillText(orderDateText,       order.date)
            fillText(deliveryDateText,    order.deliveryDate)
            fillText(cCommissionDateText, order.copyCommissionDate)
            fillText(sealDateText,        order.sealDate)
            fillText(pricelistText,       order.priceGroup)

[...]
}
```

where fillText() is this:

```
func fillText(textfield: UITextField!, value: NSDate?, altValue: String = "", prefix: String = ""){
    if let date = value {
        var formatter : NSDateFormatter = dateFormatter // That's a global variable
        if value != nil {
            textfield.text = prefix + formatter.stringFromDate(date)
        }
        else{
            textfield.text = altValue
        }
    } else {
        textfield.text = altValue
    }
}
```

When I start the application and I go to that tab, the viewWillAppear is fully computed: both deliveryDate and cCommissionDate are not nil (they are both June sixth, but they are two different instances), but after viewWillAppear and before viewDidAppear the app crashes at ... **the declaration of the AppDelegate!**

It only says `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 1`, and enabling NSZombies it says `[__NSDate release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fc0c8a0`

There are a lot of odd things: when the app crashes, I can see the last View on the emulator and that's the tab compiled. It is compiled with every date, both cCommission and deliveryDate, with June the sixth. However, the debugger can't reach the ViewDidAppear.

If I comment the `fillText(cCommissionDateText, order.copyCommissionDate)` line everything works fine.

I touch both cCommissionDate and deliveryDate only in the Textfield OnTouch listener, I never reach that part of code in this moment.

So, what could the problem be? The error is somewhere between willAppear and didAppear, but the oddest thing is that those two variables are treated in the same way, but one make the app crash and the other is ok!

Thanks in advance and I'm sorry for the long question!

Comment: Why are you checking whether value != nil after let date = value ? Value cannot be nil at that point.

Comment: It would seem that cCommissionDateText == nil.

Comment: @gnasher729: You are right, that check doesn't make any sense. Unfortunatly, that was not the -only- problem.
On the other hand cCommissionDateText is not nil, I debugged it and it is the textfield I want to populate. Thus, if it'd be nil the error would be at textfield.text = [...] line